# XCode warnings go away after subsequent Build calls

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In XCode, let's say I call a method that doesn't exist. Well, XCode gives me a nice little warning when I click "Build." Then, if I immediately click "Build" again, that warning goes away mysteriously! How do I fix this? I don't want my warnings to ever go away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the All option for your build information

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Right.  It isn't rebuilding the file that is creating the warning, so there is no new warning.  Clean and Build will make it appear again.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to clean all targets and build again :)